# Replace @INC in Perl from command line

Tags: perl

I have a perl script that used to run in a chroot, and now I'd like it to run outside the chroot. That means that I have to somehow point perl to only look for libraries and modules in /where/chroot/used/to/be/usr/lib instead of /usr/lib. I tried adding the new directories inside the script with push @INC, but then the dependencies are still broken, looking in the old dirs.

Is there any way to tell perl when I run the script that I only want it to look in certain dirs for libraries and modules?

Or is there another better way to make sure dependecies still work when the regular dirs (/usr/bin, /usr/lib etc) are replaced by nonstandard ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the @INC from the command line, use the `-I` option:

```
perl -lIadded -e 'print for @INC'
```

In a program, you need to modify @INC early enough, i.e. during compile time. This can be done with

```
BEGIN { unshift @INC, '/path/...' }
```

or by using [lib](http://p3rl.org/lib)

```
use lib '/path/...';
```

You can also set the `PERL5LIB` environment variable:

```
export PERL5LIB=/path/...
perl -e 'print for @INC'
```

Comment: @PerlDog: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **lib** to put any new directory in your program.

example

```
use lib "path";
```

in your case just add this line in the beginning of your program

```
use lib "/usr/lib/";
```

hope this will work for you.